# Comparing two Tables in Java

Tags: java, jtable, comparison

I am making an application for a project, but I have encountered myself into this situation. I'd like to compare two JTables. For instance, if the value in JTable 1 of Row 1 and Column 1 equals the other JTable, then sort the table into order of what values are the same and which aren't.

How would I do this? Is there any method in the JTable class what can do so?

I appreciate it greatly for your efforts.

Comment: The definition of the required sort order is rather sketchy. But I don't think that there's a method for it, so you'll have to code it.

Comment: `JTable` is a GUI class whose purpose is to represent how a table is displayed and can be edited by the user.  But I don't think it should be used as the main repository where the data is stored; I think you want something else, which could be a two-dimensional array or some other structure, to hold the data, and the `JTable` would just be providing a GUI view of that data.  Then the answer to your question would be how do you manipulate the data in your model, not in the `JTable`.

Comment: @ajb That is exactly what I meant, I was referring to the data in the JTable, the model. I wasn't sure how to explain it. My question still stands though: what would be a good way to compare the values?

Thanks again..

Comment: JTable already provides facilities for hooking in sorting (added with Java6): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

Comment: @ajb is correct; compare the data from the `TableModel` (model) associated with each `JTable` (view); also consider that you may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).